# Attach webform on each node of specified content type

Tags: 7, webforms

I am currently working on real-assets project in which user can add property using property-listing content type for listing and searching property on portal.

if any visitor is interested in any property than he/she can directly fill the form, which will be present in full view of property node and send it to admin and also admin will get to know for which property visitor fill the form same like as comment for node.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and found answer in drupal community, that was using of [Webform Default Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_default_fields) module.

Here are a brief description about this module :

> Description
>
> With this module you can easily create a lot of nodes with same webform fields. It can be applicable in case of job vacancies with reply form, kind of quality feedback control or whatever your mind suggests you.
>
> Because you can create more than one webform-enabled content types, you respectively can attach different default fields for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a webform and add it with [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) under all nodes of certain content-type. This is the easiest way to configure this.

Comment: but how can admin get to know for which node this form was submitted?

Comment: You can print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in your mail.

Answer (score 1):

Webform allows you to enable the webform components for any content type. Choose the types on which you would like to associate webform components.

You can configure it like the following.

1. Go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring
   (/admin/config/content/webform)
2. Select the content types which you want to add the Webform

Here in the following screenshot, I've enabled webform for Basic content type.

[image]

So this way, you add webform to content type nodes.

Comment: I can not show the view that you had posted as image on /admin/config/content/webform. its showing SHOWDEFAULT E-MAIL VALUES,SHOWPROGRESS BAR,ADVANCED OPTIONS as group and table for fields type available in webform

Comment: Webform version 4.2

Comment: i wants that the webform works same as comment work but only admin can view it.